# Finding a largest chain

Tags: set-theory

I am trying to find the cardinality of the largest chain in $(P(\omega),\subseteq)$ and $(P(\omega_{1}),\subseteq)$. So for the first one I found one with cardinality $2^{\aleph_{0}}$ by bijecting it to the reals and using dedekind cuts. But I think there must be bigger ones (like in finite sets). How do I go about finding them? Just hints :).
Thanks

Comment: Is $P(\omega)$ the power set of $\omega$? If so, how does this relate to model theory?

Comment: Since $2^{\omega_{1}}$ is not possible, any ideas on how to get a chain for P(ω1) with smaller cardinality?

Comment: Under CH, $2^{<\omega_1} = \omega_1$, so there is a chain of size $2^{\omega_1}$ in $\mathcal{P}(\omega_1)$. This was mentioned by Joel Hamkins in his answer - See the link mentioned in bof's comment above. The nontrivial result (due to Mitchell) is that this is consistently false.

Comment: What about without CH? What largest chain can we find then?

Comment: I guess you have to be more specific than just saying that CH fails. Besides Mitchell, you can also try looking at Baumgartner's thesis for some results along these lines.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum cardinality of a chain in $P(\omega)$ is at least $2^{\aleph_0}$ as you showed using Dedekind cuts, and it's no bigger than that because that's the cardinality of $P(\omega)$ itself, so it's exactly $2^{\aleph_0}$.

The same problem for $P(\omega_1)$ is much harder. The maximum cardinality of a chain in $P(\omega_1)$ is at least $2^{\aleph_0}$ because $P(\omega)\subset P(\omega_1)$, and it's at most $2^{\aleph_1}$ because $|P(\omega_1)|=2^{\aleph_1}$, but there could be lots of cardinals between $2^{\aleph_0}$ and $2^{\aleph_1}$. Actually, what I loosely referred to as "the maximum" may not exist: there is certainly a **least** cardinal $\lambda$ such that $P(\omega_1)$ does **not** contain a chain of cardinality $\lambda$, but I see no obvious reason why $\lambda$ can't be a limit cardinal. At least, the cofinality of $\lambda$ must be greater than $\omega_1$: it's easy to see that, if $P(\omega_1)$ contains a chain of cardinality $\kappa_\alpha$ for each $\alpha\lt\omega_1$, then it also contains a chain of cardinality $\kappa=\sum_{\alpha\lt\omega_1}\kappa_\alpha$.

If $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$, then there is a chain of cardinality $2^{\aleph_1}$ in $P(\omega_1)$. Hint: it's like the construction you used for $P(\omega)$, but with $\{0,1\}^{\omega_1}$ (ordered lexicographically) playing the role of $\mathbb R$, and the elements with countably many nonzero coordinates playing the role of rational numbers.

Therefore, we can prove in ZFC that there is a chain of cardinality $\aleph_2$ in $P(\omega_1)$. It's an odd proof by cases, where we use one construction if $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$, and another construction if  $2^{\aleph_0}\ge\aleph_2$. I wonder if there's a more elegant proof.

So, if either $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$ or $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}$, then there is a chain of cardinality $2^{\aleph_1}$ in $P(\omega_1)$. If $\aleph_1\lt 2^{\aleph_0}\lt2^{\aleph_1}$. we seem to be in a gray area. According to comments by Ashutosh on [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122031/totally-ordered-chain-in-the-powerset-with-big-cardinality) at Math Overflow, William Mitchell constructed a model of set theory in which $P(\omega_1)$ does **not** contain a chain of cardinality $2^{\aleph_1}$, in his paper "Aronszajn trees and the independence of the transfer property", Ann. Math. Logic 5 (1972), 21-46.

There may be some relevant information in James E. Baumgartner's paper "Almost-disjoint sets, the dense set problem and the partition calculus", Ann. Math. Logic 9 (1976), 401-439.